# UITextView - Max line breaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

When using a UITextView to gather user input in Objective-C, how can I limit the user from trying to do more than one line break at a time?

So, this would be fine:

```
This is my text.

Here is some more text.
```

But this would not be fine:

```
This is my text.




Here is some more text way down here.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewController.h add `UITextViewDelegate`:

```
YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

and in the ViewController.m implement the method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` this way:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        NSMutableString *futureString = [textView.text mutableCopy];
        [futureString insertString:text atIndex:range.location];

        NSRange rangeOflineBreaks = [futureString rangeOfString:@"\n\n\n"];
        if (rangeOflineBreaks.location != NSNotFound) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This will be executed every time before the user wants to add some text to the textView and wont let him add another line break if it notices that he wants to add a line break and it finds, after trying adding it (that's why the `futureString` name) a triple line break mode. In that case he wont let the user add another line break.

Try it out, it should work :)

PS: Don't forget to set your textView delegate the viewController in the `viewDidLoad` (`yourTextView.delegate = self`)

Comment: Do not add `UITextViewDelegate` in the .h file. Add it in the .m file with the class extension. No need to announce to the world that the class works with text views.

Comment: BTW - this code only works if the user is tapping one key at a time on the keyboard and there is no selection at the time. It doesn't work if the user pastes any text into the text view. Your calculation of `futureString` is also incorrect. It doesn't work if the user has selected any text before typing or pasting. And it doesn't handle the user deleting text.

Comment: How do I write this in Swift?